# Node.js req.body.user.username is not declared

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

Hello guys the error is req.body.user.username is not declared. Req.body.user.username is the username of the user, i would like to add req.body.user.username as their username when they chat.

**server.js**

```
//declarations
var token = require('crypto');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var client = redis.createClient();

//chat server
server.listen(80);

//confs
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(app.router);

//show redis error in case of error occurs
client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error: ' + client.host + ':' + client.port + ' - ' + err);
});


//chat service
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, req) {
  socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    socket.emit('message', { text: req.body.user.username + ':' + data.text });   
  });   
});


//route parent directory to index.html
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//if cookies exist redirect to chat room
app.get('/login/', function (req, res) {
  if(req.cookies.login_token) {
      res.redirect('/chat/')
  } else {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/login.html');
  }
});

//route to register
app.get('/register/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/register.html');
});

//chat
app.get('/chat/', function (req, res) {
  if(!req.cookies.login_token) {
    res.end('Only registered and logged in users can view this page.');
  } else {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
  }
});

//logout
app.get('/logout/', function (req, res) {
  if(!req.cookies.login_token) {
    res.end('Logged in users only can access this page!');
  } else {
    res.clearCookie('login_token');
    res.end('You has been logged out');
  }
});

//login
app.post('/login/', function (req, res) {
client.hmget( req.body.user.username, 'password', function (err,pass) {
    if ((!err) && pass && pass == req.body.user.password )  {
      require('crypto').randomBytes(48, function(ex, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        res.cookie('login_token', token);
        res.redirect('/chat/');
      });
    } else if ( pass == false) {
      res.redirect('/register/');
    } else {
      res.redirect('/login/');
    }
  });
});

    //register
app.post('/register/', function (req, res) {    
  client.hmset(req.body.user.username, 'password',req.body.user.password, 
     'fname',req.body.user.fname, 'lname', req.body.user.lname, 
     'password', req.body.user.password, 'email', req.body.user.email,
     'mobile', req.body.user.mobile, redis.print);
  res.redirect('/login/');
});
```

The part:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket, req) {
  socket.on('sendMessage', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
    socket.emit('message', { text: req.body.user.username + ':' + data.text });   
  });   
});
```

is the chat but i can't show the username because of error. Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Data stored directly on the `req` object survives only for a single request. You need this to survive for a session, so set up connect sessions, perhaps stored in redis since you are using redis and then set `req.session.user` to the object of user data and access it that way. You need quite a few code changes to make this work since the socket.io paradigm and the express paradigm don't integrate automatically. [This article](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) will have some basic pointers although you will still need to write some code yourself and make some adjustments since that article is a bit out of date.